# Volume created on lambda (boto3) does not show up in console

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

Code:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
 #create volume
 volume = ec2.create_volume(SnapshotId='snap-xxx', AvailabilityZone='us-east-1a')
 print(volume['VolumeId'])
```

Output:

```
vol-xxx
```

**Problem: After running the code, vol-xxx does not show up in console and was never created**

Details: I'm creating a volume using boto3 (from a snapshot id), and the output returns a newly created volume id. However, when I check the console, this volume id does not exist/was never created. Your input would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are checking the wrong region?

Comment: Contacted AWS support. problem is with ec2 and they're looking into it. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those wondering, I contacted AWS support and the problem is that EC2 is not detecting the volume. They're currently looking into it

EDIT: The problem was with the lambda permissions. IAM role EC2FullAccess does not have the permission to create volume. Adding PowerUserAccess to the lambda function and this fixed the problem.

Comment: So it was an AWS issue?

Comment: Thanks.  That's good to know.  I've been wracking my brain because I'm having the same issue.  Disk Manager shows the disk but from my MyComputer: de nada.

Comment: The problem was with the lambda permissions. IAM role EC2FullAccess does not have the permission to create volume. Adding PowerUserAccess to the lambda function and this fixed the problem.

Comment: I have a similar issue - if I create the volume via aws-cli, it works, while if I use boto3, it does not.